# sharepoint 2013 large file upload ( >1GB)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, large-files, large-file-upload

Does Anyone knows what is the max file size that can be uploaded through sharepoint?

I am facing an issue while uploading large file exceeding 1GB, i get an error:

Here are some solutions i tried:

1. Increase the time-out in IIS (by default It is 120 seconds, this might be changed but we can check again).
2. Increase the maximum upload size in the `web.config` file of the web application.
3. Increase the default chunk size for large files (Large-file-chunk-size: Stsadm property (Office SharePoint Server) ).
4. Add the `executionTimeout` value.
5. Increase the maximum limit for Web Parts.

I tried these and i am still getting and error while uploading these large files, here is the error:

> Sorry something went wrong, an unexpected error occured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few tricks but usually when handling such large files you are better off using a file share instead.

Increase the maximum upload size for the IIS web application, there is a maximum 
file size up to 2047 megabytes.

Open the web.config `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<Virtual Directory>` and set

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" /> to <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

There is a great post on this here, http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2012/11/16/issues-with-uploading-large-documents-on-document-library-wss-3-0-amp-moss-2007.aspx

**But first of all** I'd recommend you to have a look at RBS (Remote Blob Storage), http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748649.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot, a big help. I wish i can vote, but i need more reputation :p

Comment: @jzghaib, nice! Well you can mark it as the answer at any rep-level :)

Comment: i found out that the file is being uploaded to 100% after that the error is coming up. do that help?